# Code to access resource inside ResourceDictionary with PRISM+Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, module, prism

On an application that i'm developing using Silverlight 4 and PRISM, on one of the modules i have a ResourceDicionary with a DataTemplate.

Is there any way to get an instance of that DataTemplate using just C# code? note that the code should work on any class inside that module, not just on the controls code behind.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["MyDataTemplateKey"]
```

**EDIT:**
What about next approach?: Create UserControl with name Module as singlton. In Xaml only resources and references on resources. In code behind singleton implementation and property resources that return usercontrol resources. Now, you can use Module as Application in your code:

```
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = (DataTemplate)Module.Current.Resources["MyDataTemplateKey"]
```

Comment: this doesn´t work, remember that the resource is inside a module, so the module resources don´t belong to the application resources.